# Syncing variable between parent and multiple children angular2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a parent component called "builder", and a variable number of children called "option-1", "option-2", ..., "option-n".

The HTML for builder looks like this:

```
<b>Total: {{sharedVar}}</b>
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of color?.options">
   <button type="button" (click)="changeVar(sharedVar)"></button>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
  <app-options [options]='option'  [(sharedVar)]="sharedVar"></app-options>
</ng-container>
```

in `<app-options></app-options>` they have an identical function `changeVar` which changes `sharedVar` in the child component.

How do I register this change/update to `sharedVar` across parent + all children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'banana-in-a-box' syntax (`[()]`) can only be used in Angular with `[(NgModel)]`.

Binding the value to a component normally (`[sharedVar]`) will give it to the child component and Angular by default will update this value in the child component via change detection.

You just want to make sure `<app-options>` has an `@Input()` property set to `sharedVar`.

Comment: +1 for banana-in-a-box explanation. I am using `@input` in `app-options`, interested in looking for a way for the child to output a new sharedVar and update the parent.

Comment: That's definitely doable! You can just add an `@Output` property to the child component as an `EventEmitter`. When the value is updated, emit an event, and the parent component can bind to that event (`(outputName)="doSomething($event)`). You were on the right path by trying the banana-in-a-box, but Angular 2 doesn't two-way data bind *everything* like Angular 1 because of performance concerns, so you need to add separate input and output bindings where two-way binding is needed (you'll need a separate banana and a separate box).

Comment: Okay now the child is outputting. `(newSharedVar)="updateSharedVar($event)"`, `updateSharedVar` sets `this.sharedVar = event` GREAT! Now.. how do I make sure the children are informed of this change?

Comment: If you update the property that is bound to the child component in the parent component (`sharedVar`), Angular will automatically update the bindings to the child component. So, just use that event to update `sharedVar` in the parent component, and you should be good!

Comment: Thank you for your help!